# Input Masking not be able to store Original value

Tags: javascript, regex, masking

I have an input and I want to mask and format the value that you enter in that.I have tried with below

```
var tempVar = myInputValue.replace("/D/g","").match("/d/g{3}","/d/g{2}","/d/g{4}");
var maskedValue = myInputValue[0]."-".myInputValue[1]."-".myInputValue[2];
```

Now the formatting is coming if I enter 1234567890,it's converted `123-456-7890`. But if I wanna replace those inputs with 'x', it is only changing the first character that I enter, but from second key press,since we are restricting characters, it is removing first 'x'.

I just want to change the entered number into "x" and retrieve the original value that I entered. Please suggest me a good way to do it. Thanks in Advance.Don't close this as I searched alot for this.

Comment: Can you provide an expected output?

Comment: 1234567890 to xxx-xx-xxxx on each key press and same time maintain the entered string considering backspace and delete as well. Suppose if I go to 6 and delete it then in my actual value I have to get like 123457890 and display in popup as with x

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = ''
function keyDown()
{
  console.clear()
  event.preventDefault()

  if (!isNaN(event.key) & data.length <= 9) {
    data += event.key
    var mask = data.replace(/\d/g, "x")
    if (data.length > 3) {
      mask = mask.slice(0, 3) + "-" + mask.slice(3);
      if (data.length > 6) {
        mask = mask.slice(0, 7) + "-" + mask.slice(7);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("input").value = mask
  }
  document.getElementById("divOutput").innerHTML = data
  console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" onkeydown="keyDown()"></br>
Original value (var data): <div id="divOutput"></div>
```

Comment: I think this answers OP's partial query. However, what happens in the event that a user wants to hit a backspace? From UX pov, backspace must be supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, I think what you try to do is something like this:

```
var tempVar = myInputValue.replace(/\D/g,"").match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
var maskedValue = tempVar[1] + "-" + tempVar[2] + "-" + tempVar[3];
maskedValue.replace(/\d/g, "x"); // xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

Look closely at the regExp in replace and match, to capture those values you need to wrap them with parentheses.

Comment: But need to store the actual string right. It will convert 123 to xxx but how can I maintain actual string data. Considering backspace and delete at any position